# Zend Framework "under maintenance" page

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a holding/"under maintenance" page in Zend Framework for when I am upgrading the database or something and don't want anyone using the site. I'd like to have a static HTML page and have all traffic redirected to that.

I'd rather not use .htaccess and would like to do it via the bootstrap file.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this by creating a plugin that check the validity of the request each time that a page is requested.

During the execution of the plugin in the "preDispatch()" you can analyze a variable from the config that it will hold your current status as active/under maintenance and let the request flow to the original destination or redirect it to a landing page for this purpose.

Code sample

```
public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{
    // get your user and your config
    if( $config->suspended && $user->role()->name != "admin"){
        $request
            ->setModuleName( 'default' )
            ->setControllerName( 'index' )
            ->setActionName( 'suspended' )
            ->setDispatched(true)
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm interested in you approach Elzo can you elaborate a bit on this.thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've set Apache to show index.html in preference to index.php (which bootstraps the ZF).  As long as you don't link directly to /index.php anywhere, then you can just drop in an index.html file, and it will show that in preference to the ZF site.

An alternative is to have an entry in your configuration .ini file, and as soon as you have read the configuration:

```
if ($config->maintenance) {
    readfile(APPLICATION . '/../public/maintenance.html');
    exit;
}
```

You may want to add another check in there for a particular IP address (your own) as well, so that you can get though even when everyone else is blocked.

Answer (score 1):

You could check your configuration file for a `maintenance_mode` switch and redirect every request from within the bootstrap to your static html maintenance page.

Answer (score 1):

I have a blog post that demonstrates how to do this.  [Setting up a maintenance page with Zend Framework](http://www.eschrade.com/page/setting-maintenance-page-with-zend-framework-4bcdce41)

Comment: @WebinarsatZend has already tweet about your blogpost http://twitter.com/WebinarsatZend/status/12526221389

Answer (score 0):

I would use plugin with `dispatchLoopShutdown()` and based on the config settings i would redirect the request to any controller you want.

Answer (score 0):

I followed all of these suggestions to a TEE on Zend 1.12. I googled around. Tried using application.ini, setting the plugin path, using zend_loader_autoloader_resource(), using Zend_Loader_PluginLoader. NONE of these worked for me. I ended up writing a .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /maintenance.php [R=503,L]
```

This is why Zend is the worst framework. Tons of different options on how to do something simple, Official Documentation is extremely ambiguous and unclear, and nobody fully understands or can explain the correct way to do anything so I end up wasting an hour of my time trying to do things correctly.